# Modify datetime column in pandas based on value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, typeerror

I've got a column with months as integers and a variable storing the current day in daytime format. I need to create a column with the month updated:

```
df_final["Date"] = current_day.replace(month=df_final["Month"])
```

but I get the following error:

```
/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 185, in wrapper
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I'm not sure why, any suggestions?

Comment: Most of the documentation I am seeing is using .replace(['old value'],'new value'), haven't seen any single param overloads but I would start with that. Also are you updating the month variable with the column?

Edit: Sorry should have added [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: try `df_final['Date'] + pd.DateOffset(Month=df_final['Month'])` for datetime operands you need to use the appropriate function `.replace` is for strings.

Answer (score 0):

A small example of df_final would be apreciated, however the error is pretty clear df_final["Date"] is a series i.e. a column of values in your dataframe whereas current_day is an integer.
I think what you need is apply https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Where you replace each value of your datettime object with the month column.

df_final.apply(lambda row: row["Date"].replace(month=row["Month"])) might work but would probably give a setting with copy issue. And it also might be slow depending on the size of your df.